# Windows 10 automatically locks out with TeamViewer remote access

Tags: windows, windows-10, teamviewer, login-screen

I just purchased my new PC and installed Windows 10 and it was looking good.
Until I updated my Win10 to 1903 and Build number is 18362.356.

Then the problem starts. I log into my Windows and with a random number of seconds, usually it is just a couple of seconds, Windows 10 logs me out. And it happens all the time no matter how many times I have logged into.(this happened 2 days ago without using TeamViewer). Then I used my computer yesterday without any forced-log-out-Windows-10 issue. Then today, I started to use TeamViewer to connect to my computer, the problem comes again.

The version of TeamViewer I'm using to connect to my computer from my company's laptop is 14.5.5819 and it should be the same version on my computer.

Please help, it's such a painful situation! I got my shiny and super powerful new hardware assembled and everything is ready and I want to play the beast computer, but the Windows 10 just stops me to enjoy my new toy.....

---

Update

I found [this article](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-security/windows-10-is-locking-itself/c2b18d4f-59e2-4084-abe8-bc4b77f35aa6), will give it a try once I'm home.

I am back to home and this issue doesn't appear anymore. I guess it's a TeamViewer related issue?

Comment: The body of your question doesn't explain what TeamViewer has to do with it.

Comment: The current version of TeamViewer absolutely supports Windows 10 version 1903 which is the current version of Windows 10.  Any other build is either reaching end of support very quickly, has reached end of support already, or is an Insider Preview build which is unsupported.  Please edit your question to specify the exact version you are using.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator hi there, I updated my post to address what TV has to do with it.

Comment: @Ramhound hi there, I updated my post to include the TV version.

Comment: You didn’t confirm what version of Windows 10 you have installed

Comment: @Ramhound updated. it's 1903.